# Remove various div according specific text in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this DOM and I want to make like a filter removing li according text included in h5 tag.

```
<div class="total">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>this super heroe is super cool: Clark Kent</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>I always wanted to be Batman</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>Somedays I will be transform as Spiderman </h5>
   </li>
 </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>This women is incredible Catwoman</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

   <li>
    <ul>
     <h5>The worst character is Joker</h5>
   </ul>
   </li>

   <ul>
    <li>
     <h5>Someone knows about Green Lantern </h5>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to make a filter according string into this array which has not coma

```
let appDataTab = ["Clark Kent    Catwoman     Joker"]
```

My goal is to remove all **li** that its h5 doesn't content "Clark Kent" "Catwoman" and "Joker"
As you can see the appDataTab content these string with no separation.

Comment: Is there a separator in `appDataTab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code after adding additional code after validating from my end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="total">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>this super heroe is super cool: Clark Kent</h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>I always wanted to be Batman</h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>Somedays I will be transform as Spiderman </h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>This women is incredible Catwoman</h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>The worst character is Joker</h5>
            </li>
        </ul>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h5>Someone knows about Green Lantern </h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var prohibited = ['Clark Kent', 'Catwoman', 'Joker'];

            $("li").each(function (index) {
                var wordFound = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < prohibited.length; i++) {

                    if ($(this).text().indexOf(prohibited[i]) > -1) {
                        wordFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (wordFound == false) {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should first make it a regular comma seperated array, then look for the element and remove the `li` containing the element.

Steps are commented one by one:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
//Your array
var appDataTab = ["Clark Kent    Catwoman     Joker"];
//Split with more than 1 space (2 space)
var appDataSplit = appDataTab[0].split("  ");
//Remove empty elements
var filtered = appDataSplit.filter(function (el) {
  return el != "";
});
//Trim elements from extra spaces
var cleanFiltered = [];
for (i=0; i < filtered.length; i++){
  cleanFiltered.push(filtered[i].trim());
}
console.log(cleanFiltered);
//look for any li containing the words in cleanFilter array
  $("li").each(function(){
    for (i=0; i < cleanFiltered.length;i++){
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(cleanFiltered[i]) > -1) {
        $(this).remove();
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>this super heroe is super cool: Clark Kent</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>I always wanted to be Batman</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>Somedays I will be transform as Spiderman </h5>
   </li>
 </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <h5>This women is incredible Catwoman</h5>
   </li>
  </ul>

   <ul>
    <li>
     <h5>The worst character is Joker</h5>
   </li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
    <li>
     <h5>Someone knows about Green Lantern </h5>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```